# Linux Split command very slow on AWS Instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, split, linux-kernel

I have deployed my application in AWS Instance and my application is using some linux system commands which is called via simple shell script.

Below is the sample script content:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "File Split started"
cd /prod/data/java/
split -a 5 -l 100000000 samplefile.dat
echo "File Split Completed"
```

Actually the same script was running faster in our local server. In Local Server it was taking 15 minutes to complete , but in AWS Instance it took 45 minutes. This is huge difference.

**Update:** Also in AWS its not using more CPU, hardly 2 to 5 percentage, thats why its very slow.

Both are 64 bit OS and Local server is RHEL 5(2.6.18) , AWS is RHEL 6(2.6.xx)

Can anyone help on this?

Regards,
Shankar

Comment: What kind of volume is `/prod/data/java` on ? You may be able to attach one with better IO performance.

Comment: I am splitting multiple files.. the total volume of files is around 100GB(700M records)

Comment: No, I mean, what kind of disk (harddisk or SSD, directly attached or over network).

Comment: It is SSD and the files are in AWS same server.

Comment: SSD in EBS or ephemeral?  Particularly if EBS, is this a new volume?  Did you properly pre-warm it first?

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot  Its EBS. I am not sure how to pre-warm.. Will look into this.

Comment: Hi @Michael-sqlbot if we did not pre-warm it whats going to happen, is the slowness going to be there for permanently or it will go away after few runs.

Comment: It clears itself over time.  The space in EBS is allocated when you provision a volume (new and blank, or from a snapshot) but each block may not actually be initialized on the EBS media (by the initial zero-out, or by copying from the source snapshot) until each block is first accessed.  So it takes care of itself with use.  Filling the disk with large zero-filled files (e.g. `pv -pterab /dev/zero > /prod/data/java/deleteme`) then removing that file will mostly do it.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot we are using c3.4xlarge model, it says SSD backed storage, does it means it is different from EBS? If yes how this will affect performance.. Because i heard SSD will be faster compare to HDD , but still it takes the same time as HDD.

Comment: HI @Michael-sqlbot we tried c3.8xlarge instance as well, the file splitting is very slow , its taking 30 minutes ( even if we are running multiple split command in parallel).. its not at all using CPU.

Comment: Hi @Thilo do you have any solution for this? we are using c3.8xlarge instance. but split command is using very less percentage of CPU(only 2% CPU utilization and its like 32 core processor ,taking 30 minutes to split files).. Actually in local server(HDD based), it took only 15 minutes(same 32 core processor).