# Which is faster split by line or file size

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, split, amazon-emr

We are getting big 3 to 4 GB zipped file in `S3` bucket , we have to split the file before loading into snowflake cloud database.
We are using below command to split. And it is taking 2 hrs to split the files. All this i am doing in AWS EMR. How can i enhance it,  which is faster split by file size or line no..

**UPDATE**

```
aws s3 cp s3://filename - | zcat | split -d -l 1000000 --filter 'aws s3 cp - s3://location/filename
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Snowflake. Is it taking 2hours per file or for all files? How big are the unzipped files? What is the format of the unzipped files?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to split the files before loading to Snowflake - have you tried loading them directly?

Comment: What is the format of the files? If you really need to do this, you might be able to use Amazon Athena rather than Amazon EMR.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa we compare both with split and direct load of compressed file we are gaining around 40 minutes performance with split.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein FIle format is CSV

Comment: @Sergiu Unzipped file is 330 GB around

Comment: This might be related to AWS as I've seen other people saying the same, see this old [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819252/linux-split-command-very-slow-on-aws-instance). What about trying combining with other utilities, like *parallel* or *pigz*?

Comment: i have updated the exact command we are using. Could you please suggest any where we can improve.